# Wireguard limiting access to services and machines in local network

Tags: iptables, wireguard

I'm running a Wireguard "Server" in my local network, that i reach remotely through my static public IP.
I want to be able to limit access to Wireguard remote peers to services/machines in my lan, where i host other server.

Example:
Server 1 (192.168.1.23 | 10.0.0.1) with Wireguard installed + Nextcloud + Jellyfin in same machine
Server 2 (192.168.1.62) with Photoprism

Remote peer 1 (10.0.0.2 | dynamic ip)
Remote peer 2 (10.0.0.3 | dynamic ip)

I want to:

1- Allow peer1 (10.0.0.2) to access Server 1 Nextcloud + Jellyfin and access to Server 2 to Photoprism.

2- Allow Peer2 (10.0.0.3) to only access Server 1 Nextcloud but not Jellyfin and block access to Server 2

Right now i can access all machines in my lan from all Peers.

Iptables rules:

```
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s7 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp0s7 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o wg0
```

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.procustodibus.com/blog/2021/04/wireguard-access-control-with-iptables/#point-to-site), from [Justin Ludwig](https://serverfault.com/users/33888/justin-ludwig) because Site to Point topology is very similar to mine.
So i tried to replicate Iptables rules with these rules:

```
# masquerading
PreUp = iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i wg0 -j MARK --set-mark 0x200
PreUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -o wg0 -m mark --mark 0x200 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -t mangle -D PREROUTING -i wg0 -j MARK --set-mark 0x200
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING ! -o wg0 -m mark --mark 0x200 -j MASQUERADE

# wireguard ingress
PreUp = iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 2332 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D INPUT -p udp --dport 2332 -j ACCEPT

# site firewall
PreUp = iptables -N wg0-filter
PreUp = iptables -N to-photoprism
PreUp = iptables -N to-jellyfin
PreUp = iptables -N to-nextcloud

PreUp = iptables -I INPUT   -i wg0 -j wg0-filter
PreUp = iptables -I FORWARD -i wg0 -j wg0-filter
PreUp = iptables -I FORWARD -o wg0 -j wg0-filter
PreUp = iptables -I OUTPUT  -o wg0 -j wg0-filter

PreUp = iptables -A wg0-filter -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
PreUp = iptables -A wg0-filter -d 192.168.1.63  -p tcp --dport   2342 -j to-photoprism
PreUp = iptables -A wg0-filter -d 192.168.1.23  -p tcp --dport   8096 -j to-jellyfin
PreUp = iptables -A wg0-filter -d 192.168.1.23  -p tcp --dport     80 -j to-nextcloud
PreUp = iptables -A wg0-filter -j REJECT

PreUp = iptables -A to-photoprism     -s 10.0.0.2    -j ACCEPT

PreUp = iptables -A to-jellyfin       -s 10.0.0.2    -j ACCEPT
PreUp = iptables -A to-jellyfin       -s 10.0.0.3    -j ACCEPT

PreUp = iptables -A to-nextcloud      -s 10.0.0.2    -j ACCEPT
PreUp = iptables -A to-nextcloud      -s 10.0.0.3    -j ACCEPT

PostDown = iptables -D INPUT   -i wg0 -j wg0-filter
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j wg0-filter
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -o wg0 -j wg0-filter
PostDown = iptables -D OUTPUT  -o wg0 -j wg0-filter

PostDown = iptables -F to-photoprism
PostDown = iptables -F to-jellyfin
PostDown = iptables -F to-nextcloud

PostDown = iptables -X to-photoprism
PostDown = iptables -X to-jellyfin
PostDown = iptables -X to-nextcloud
```

This didn't worked,
Peer 1 and Peer 2 can reach Server 1, both services, but not Server 2.

I'm not so savvy to understand what i have to change to make this work, I would be happy if someone can chime in.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall your iptables rules look good to me; although:

1. In the question description, you mention Server 2 has an IP address of `192.168.1.62`; but in in the iptables rules, you seem to be using `192.168.1.63` for it:

   ```
    iptables -A wg0-filter -d 192.168.1.63  -p tcp --dport   2342 -j to-photoprism
   ```

   Is that a typo in one place or the other?
2. In the description, you mention Peer 2 (`10.0.0.3`) should not have access to Jellyfin; but in the iptables rules, you grant it access with this line:

   ```
    iptables -A to-jellyfin       -s 10.0.0.3    -j ACCEPT
   ```

   Perhaps you meant to remove this rule?
3. I don't see any `PostDown` commands to tear down the `wg0-filter` chain, like you have for the other custom chains; make sure you include them:

   ```
    PostDown = iptables -F wg0-filter
    PostDown = iptables -X wg0-filter
   ```

   Without these tear-down commands, if you make changes and restart, the `wg0-chain` may end up using the old rules from previous attempts, instead of newer updates. (And make sure you follow the [Making Config Changes](https://www.procustodibus.com/blog/2021/04/wireguard-access-control-with-iptables/#making-config-changes) advice from the article, to shut down the WireGuard interface before making config changes and restarting -- run `sudo iptables-save` when the interface is down to double-check if you have any old rules or chains that haven't been cleaned up.)

Comment: Thanks a lor for taking the tame to answer to my sloppy post.
I'm really sorry for being sloppy. The ip was indeed wrong in my wg0.conf file.
The "PostDown = iptables -X wg0-filter" was just a typo doing the post.
Not it works as it should.
Thanks for the great tutorials and write-ups!